# githubで保管している公開鍵は他の環境でのssh接続時に使用できるのでしょうか？

Tags: github, ssh

### 前提

githubとエディターをssh接続するため鍵を作成しました。次の画像のような状態になっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 疑問点

各環境ごとに鍵を作成し、githubに登録しました。
ここで疑問に思ったのですが、例えば環境Aで作成した公開鍵Aを環境Bや環境Cで使用することはできるのでしょうか？
環境ごとに鍵を作成すると公開鍵が大量になると思いました。

また、ローカルに秘密鍵を持っていて、秘密鍵を保管している『.sshフォルダ』に次の画像のような秘密鍵と公開鍵の2種類がある状態です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

公開鍵はgithubに登録しているはずなのになぜ『.sshフォルダ』にあるのかがわかりません。

### お願いしたいこと

そもそも鍵は使いまわせるのか。
使いまわせる場合エディターの種類に関係なく、設定によって使いまわせるのか。
使いまわせる場合どういったやり方をするべきなのか。
『.sshフォルダ』には秘密鍵と公開鍵両方が保管されるものなのか。
といった点についてご教示いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Authenticating with GitHub from Git](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/set-up-git#authenticating-with-github-from-git)には

- Connecting over HTTPS (recommended)
- Connecting over SSH

の２種類の接続方法が説明されており、特にHTTPSが推奨されています。逆に質問で触れられているSSH Keyを使った接続・認証方法は推奨されていません。

またHTTPS接続の場合の[認証のキャッシュ方法](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git)として

- GitHub CLI
- Git Credential Manager (Git for Windowsにも付属）

が用意されています。各環境にGitHub CLIをインストールし、`gh auth login`をしておくのが推奨された手順だと思います。